# 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

Tags: python, discord

I'm returning a string but it says it's not working.
I'm somewhat new to discord bot coding and am confused.

#### Code

```
from python_aternos import Client

aternos = Client.from_credentials('test', '123')
servs = aternos.list_servers()

testserv = None
for serv in servs:
    if serv.address == 'server.aternos.me':
        testserv = serv

def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message == 'status':
        return str(serv.status)
    # Here the issue starts
    if p_message == 'Start':
        serv.start(False,True)
        return "test"
    # Here the issue ends
    if p_message == 'help':
            return "Status - Tells the status of the server.\nStart - Starts the server for people to play.\nHelp - Lists all the commands."
```

I tried to return a string and then use the `start` command but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your `p_message` is always a lower-case string. Thus, you likely wan to compare it with `'start'` rather than `'Start'`?

Comment: additionally to the above i would suggest to add a default response

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does the question have to do with Minecraft? I can't understand.